# Creating a scheduled job from GCS --> Pandas dataframe --> BQ every night

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am completely new to Google Cloud!

For the last several days I have tried to create a job directly in BigQuery that will do the following:

1. Each night a .csv file is uploaded to a gcs-bucket
2. I would like to extract the contents of this .csv-file, do some light data wrangling on the file using Python
3. Upload and overwrite the file to an already existing BigQuery table
4. This job should be automated either everytime the new .csv-file is uploaded or just at a specific time that I choose

Can someone please explain if this is possible in Google Cloud. Please have in mind that I am very new in the whole Google Cloud world.

Thank you so much! :-)

Tried using Cloud Functions, Google CLI etc., however I am currently not able to write the data from the .csv-file to BigQuery

Comment: Can you ingest the CSV (first step) directly in BigQuery ? Do you really need python for data wrangling or is it translatable in SQL?